# How to design one to many relationship in efcore?

Tags: c#, .net, ef-core-2.0

Hi I am working on entity framework core. I have user table and user may be part of multiple projects. And user for each project has to enter time sheet data. For example below is my user table.

```
public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string emailId { get; set; }
    }
```

Below is my project table.

```
 public class Project
    {
        [Key]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string userId { get; set; }
    }
```

Here User may belong to multiple projects. Now for each project user has to enter timesheet data. Below is timesheet table.

```
public class TimeSheetData
    {
        [Key]
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string project_id { get; set; }
        public string hours_logged { get; set; }
    }
```

I have to define this in entity framework core. One user may be part of multiple projects and user needs to enter data to timesheet for each project. How can I define relationship with respect to above table?

In user table Do I need to add something like `Public List<Project> Projects`? Also In Project table `Public List<Timesheet> Timesheets` something I have to define here. Can some one help me to understand this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: why are you using string data type for Keys?

Comment: Okay I will change it to int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you will be changing string to int ids, does something below work?

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Projects = new HashSet<Project>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string emailId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set;}
}

public class Project
{   
    public Project()
    {
        this.TimeSheetData = new HashSet<TimeSheetData>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int userId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("userId")]
    public virtual User User {get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TimeSheetData> TimeSheetData { get; set;}
}

public class TimeSheetData
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int project_id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("project_id")]
    public virtual Project Project {get; set; }
    public string hours_logged { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks I will test. Assuming in project class constructor is Public Project() right and not user?

Comment: @Niranjan Yes, Thanks for pointing it out. I have updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: Also If i pass user id as input how can I get timesheetdata for particular user? _context.Users.Where(s => s.Id == userid).Include(s => s.Projects) after this how can I include timesheet data?

Comment: Hi Sam I changed everything and compiles with no errors but thinking how to timesheet of each user for each projects? May I know this?

Comment: _context.Users.Include(s => s.Projects.TimeSheetData).Where(s => s.Id == userid). When you include TimeSheetData, Projects will automatically be included. The above statement will return all projects including all TimeSheetData for the given userId

Comment: I am not getting Projects.TimeSheetData. may i know I need to change any class?

Comment: I do not get you. Is that line giving any compiler errors? or your resultset does not contain TimeSheetData?

Comment: Yes exactly. does not contain definition for TimeSheetData

Comment: Do you have this last line public virtual ICollection<TimeSheetData> TimeSheetData { get; set;} in your Project class?

Comment: Yes It is there.  when i type dot after projects its giving me  add , aggregare , all etc. Its not giving me property timesheetdata

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206461/discussion-between-niranjan-and-sam).

Comment: You need to use the System.Data.Entity namespace that is part of EF package. Please refer the fiddler: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rYOeTt